# How is value assigned to "other" variable in this Python Class?

Tags: python, class, oop

I am doing this Python Edx course, and one of the examples given during introduction to OOP is below. It is a basic question, lot of you will downvote it, but I need to understand this before I move ahead.

I have already searched on Reddit and asked this question on the Edx forums too, but still don't understand it. I have searched this website too for this specific coding example.

Reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/a54y04/explanation_needed_on_a_simple_class_creation/

```
class Coordinate(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def distance(self, other):
        x_diff_sq = (self.x-other.x)**2
        y_diff_sq = (self.y-other.y)**2
        return (x_diff_sq + y_diff_sq)**0.5

point1 = Coordinate(1,2)
point2 = Coordinate(3,4)

print(point1.distance(point2))
```

What I want to understand is that how is "other.x" value determined by the program? Because I am nowhere assigning a value to other.x and other.y.

For self.x and self.y, there is an explicit assignment happening, but there is no such assignment for "other.x" and "other.y". How does the program assign "3" to "other.x" and "4" to "other.y"?

Comment: The program creates `point1` and `point2`, then calls `point1.distance(point2)`. In this case, `point2` is the argument that is passed for the parameter `other` of method `distance` and contains 3 and 4 for `.x` and `.y` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

`other` is just the argument that the method `distance` is taking. It is implicitly expected that this argument has the `x` and `y` attributes. Whether they really exist or are assigned or not is not a concern for the method `distance`.

> How does the program assign "3" to "other.x" and "4" to "other.y"?

Again, as said before, `other` is just the name of the argument of the function. Lets look at the only place where you call the function:

```
print(point1.distance(point2))
```

This is interpreted as `self.distance(other)`, so we can conclude that in this particular case, `other` is the object `point2`.

Now, lets go back a few lines to find any reference of `point2`. Here it is:

```
point2 = Coordinate(3,4)
```

When doing `Coordinate(3,4)` we are invoking the `__init__` method of the class. So in that method, we assigning `x` with `3` and `y` with `4`.

So you are right, there is no explicit assignment for `other.x` and `other.y`, but `other` is not really an object but an argument. So you have to understand which object it is for a specific function call, and that trace where it is being assigned.

---

Don't let argument names confuse you!

> For self.x and self.y, there is an explicit assignment happening

This is not entirely true as well. Yes a few lines back there is an assignment to `self` but that's just the same name for two different functions' arguments. The code could be written like this and still work the same:

```py
class Coordinate(object):
    def __init__(obj, x, y):
        obj.x = x
        obj.y = y

    def distance(one, two):
        x_diff_sq = (one.x-two.x)**2
        y_diff_sq = (one.y-two.y)**2
        return (x_diff_sq + y_diff_sq)**0.5
```

Here you would say that there is no explicit assignment to `one`. But it all depends on each call of each function, what arguments it is being passed.

Comment: That is quite an explanation. "It is implicitly expected that this argument is of type Coordinate, so that it would have the x and y attributes." - so this means that whenever a method (apart from __init__) is define inside a class, the argument for that method will always be of the same type as the class? Am I correct in this?

Comment: No. Sorry if I misled you. I will try to clarify the explanation. It is simply expected that these objects will have `x` and `y` attributes (since we are explicitly accessing them...)

Comment: Your part about "argument names confuse you!" was what helped me. So when I call 'distance' method, what is actually happening is that the data attributes of point1 & point2 are getting assigned to "one" and "two" (referring to your code). So now "one" and "two" have data attributes which are exactly similar to those data attributes of point1 and point2. Is this correct?

Comment: yes exactly. `one` is a reference to same object as `point1` and `two` is a reference to same object as `point2`. So that's why when doing `one.x` etc. you get the expected data